# How to @ mention a user in a comment (to reply to a user's comment)

Tags: support

How can I "mention" or "tag" a specific user in a comment?

The goal is to respond/reply to a comment from a specific user and to draw that user's attention.

I seem to remember being able to type `@username` for this but that doesn't (always?) work.

Example: [How to add X-Forwarded-for header in reverse proxy with SSL passthrough](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627492/how-to-add-x-forwarded-for-header-in-reverse-proxy-with-ssl-passthrough?noredirect=1#comment1174290_627492) I want to reply to Steffen Ulrich's comment.
Then I type `@stef` a pop-up dialog is shown with `SteffenUlrich` and I can click that pop-up to complete the username.
Yet when I do I don't see any indication that this is a link.

I tried to add a dash between `Steffen` and `Ulrich` because the user's profile URL contains a dash but that does not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a link, but the 'ping' works. As @AdminBee notes in the comments, only the first three characters matter. That the space disappears when you click his name

[image]

is expected behaviour. What might surprise you is that you do not even need to mention his name to ping him; since you're the only two users in that comment thread, he is automatically notified.

For more information, see the [Help Center article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) or the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/295232)

Comment: Heh, you beat me there ;) Just a comment: The [Help page indicates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) that only the first three letters after the `@` are actually used for user matching when pinging, so this kind of typo should not matter in addressing the user mentioned here.